# which is better, dead or deceased or passed away?

Tags: word-choice

I was not able to serve the letter to Mario because he is dead.

I was not able to serve the letter to Mario because he is deceased.

I was not able to serve the letter to Mario because he passed away.

Comment: *Dead* would be the most *U-English* (Google it). And welcome to the site!

Comment: "serve the letter"? Perhaps *give*, *deliver*, or *send* would sound better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA in finance and law, delivering formal correspondence is often called "serving the letter." I agree your alternative sound better, but in some cases this wording is necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by *better*?

Comment: *Deceased* is the most formal of the three.

Comment: Should you use the expression *serve the letter*, the right pairing to go with it would only be *deceased*. That's fine.

Answer (score 4):

Deceased is professional. Passed away is caring. Dead is... Uh... A bit harsh, maybe?

Comment: +1 But that's not **an** answer :)

Comment: Well I think the answer depends on how you want to deal with the situation. How do you want to be perceived by the recipient? As David pointed out, deceased is formal. What do you mean by "better"? In which way should the term be better? :)

Answer (score 0):

Dead or deceased are the more correct usages.  Deceased is far more formal, but if you are speaking of serving someone with a letter, you likely wish to be formal.

But, typically I would use a more passive voice here:

I was not able to serve the letter to Mario due to his being deceased.

This is merely a stylistic point, but to my ear it sounds better.